# w3schools.com Image Modal, need to launch automatically

Tags: jquery, css, image, modal-dialog

I have sucessfully managed to get this actual script working BUT I need the modal to launch on page load rather than an image click - please help.

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modal_images.asp

Thanks in advance

Paul

Comment: can u show what u have already done?

Comment: Hello - yes it's on that link thanks

Comment: try to set window.onload function and inside of it set #myModal display block, or just set it block by default

Comment: For future reference, W3Schools is an extremely unreliable source as their articles are often outdated and sometimes just plain wrong. I'd suggest avoiding them in future.

Comment: Thank you everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using window.onload instead of onclick, following the w3schools tutorial change this

```
img.onclick = function(){
  modal.style.display = "block";
  modalImg.src = this.src;
  captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
}
```

to this:

```
window.onload = function(){
  modal.style.display = "block";
  modalImg.src = img.src;
  captionText.innerHTML = img.alt;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

instead, try to change the `IMG.onclick` to `window.onload`

```js
window.onload = function(){
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = img.src;
    captionText.innerHTML = img.alt;
}
```